# Nothing appears in my console after "php artisan queue:work"

Tags: php, laravel, queue

I've been having this problem for days and I don't know how to solve it.

I have a job that I'm dispatching from my controller, but once I do `php artisan queue:work` nothing shows up in my console (not windows, not a Linux terminal emulator like Cmder)

My job:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use App\Models\ProfessorSuscription;
use App\Models\ProfessorSuscriptionHistory;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class CheckSuscription implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $suscription_history = new ProfessorSuscriptionHistory();
        $suscription_history->user_id = 13;
        $suscription_history->type = 'trimestral';
        $suscription_history->pdf = 'test.pdf';
        $suscription_history->ended_at = Carbon::now()->addMonth(3);
        $suscription_history->save();

    }
}
```

That is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Jobs\CheckSuscription;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        CheckSuscription::dispatchNow();
    }
}
```

Note: when I execute my controller by route, it works perfectly and saves me in the database

My queue config:

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
```

After i do `php artisan queue:work`:

[image]

PD: I used commands `php artisan queue:table`, `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan config:clear`

PD2: Nothing appears too in my jobs or failed_jobs table.

PD3: Nothing appears in my laravel.log related to my Job.

How can i fix it? I've searched for days and can't find a solution. Thank you.

EDIT: `config/queue.php` file:

```
'default' => env('QUEUE_CONNECTION', 'sync'),

'connections' => [

    'sync' => [
        'driver' => 'sync',
    ],

    'database' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'jobs',
        'queue' => 'default',
        'retry_after' => 90,
        'after_commit' => false,
    ],

    'beanstalkd' => [
        'driver' => 'beanstalkd',
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'queue' => 'default',
        'retry_after' => 90,
        'block_for' => 0,
        'after_commit' => false,
    ],

    'sqs' => [
        'driver' => 'sqs',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'prefix' => env('SQS_PREFIX', 'https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/your-account-id'),
        'queue' => env('SQS_QUEUE', 'default'),
        'suffix' => env('SQS_SUFFIX'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION', 'us-east-1'),
        'after_commit' => false,
    ],

    'redis' => [
        'driver' => 'redis',
        'connection' => 'default',
        'queue' => env('REDIS_QUEUE', 'default'),
        'retry_after' => 90,
        'block_for' => null,
        'after_commit' => false,
    ],

],

'failed' => [
    'driver' => env('QUEUE_FAILED_DRIVER', 'database-uuids'),
    'database' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
    'table' => 'failed_jobs',
],
```

Comment: Because there is no queue

Comment: @Ainz can u explain me that? pls

Comment: `dispatchNow()` triggers the job on the same process so it never reach the queue and is executed on the spot. use `dispatch()` instead

Comment: @N69S i tried to use `CheckSuscription::dispatch()->onQueue('default');` but doesnt work anyway. I dont understand what is wrong.

Comment: If I get you right, there is no database entry in jobs table after running the `CheckSubscription::dispatch()` method? What's in your `config/queue.php`file?

Comment: Exact @OnkiHara also, when I do the `php artisan queue:work` command, nothing shows up in my console. It stays stuck. I update the post with the content of my `config/queue.php` file.

Comment: Looks everything fine to me. Just to be sure, your .env file contents get loaded, replace temporarily `'default' => env('QUEUE_CONNECTION', 'sync')`with `'default' => 'database'` in config/queue.php and do a `artisan config:clear` and `artisan cache:clear`.

Comment: @OnkiHara I've tried but it doesn't work anyway. I don't know what could be going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should set QUEUE_CONNECTION=database in your env file or to change the config/queue.php default value to database. After that you should use CheckSuscription::dispatch(); instead.